# CSS animation hover effect

Tags: css

I'm looking for some help with a CSS hover effect.

I have a border effect at the bottom of the div horizontal on hover.
How do I set it to working vertical right side of div when hover?

Comment: Put a [mcve] *in the question*.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the effect on hover on the right border and in the meantime remove the effect on the bottom, like in the example below:

```
div:hover {border-right: 1px solid red; border-bottom-style: none;}
```

Comment: You're welcome. The code that i posted applies a border right on hover and makes the border on the bottom disappear. Which kind of effect are you aiming for?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand very well. You should provide some code in the question so we can help you more.